# Is there an EffectController function in Flame/Flutter that allows you to change animation?

Tags: flutter, flame

I'm currently using Flutter and Flame to create a simulation that runs through a set of instructions.  Each instruction adds an effect to the character by using effect queue that uses MoveByEffect and EffectController.  I want the character to change into a different color for one of the instructions.  Is there a similar command to the previous two mentioned that can do that?

I either want to tint the character or I have tinted a version of the sprite that can run as that color.  Right now I'm trying to delay the character turning colors with a countdown timer, but it either changes color at the beginning of the instructions or the end.

Is there something that can work with this kind of code?

```
if (effectQueue.isNotEmpty && children.query<Effect>().isEmpty) {
      add(effectQueue.removeAt(0));
    }

effectQueue.add(MoveByEffect(Vector2((moveLength), 0), EffectController(duration: 1)));
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit, do you want to run the tinting after the other effects are done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ColorEffect` for this, you can see an example of it [here](https://examples.flame-engine.org/#/Effects_Color%20Effect).

Basically you use it like this:

```dart
yourComponent.add(
  ColorEffect(
    Colors.blue,
    const Offset(
      0.0,
      0.8,
    ), // Means, applies from 0% to 80% of the color
    EffectController(
      duration: 1.5,
      reverseDuration: 1.5,
      infinite: true,
    ),
  ),
);
```